# Having Wirless adapter problems in BackTrack 5 R3

Tags: wifi, backtrack

I am trying to get a wireless connection on BackTrack 5 R3, but as soon as I boot up the BackTrack VM, the light on the adapter turns off.  Drivers are installed and the VM detects the USB device. I am using an Asus N-13 wireless adapter to connect. It works fine on Ubuntu 12.10 (my host), and Windows 7. However, when I boot the BackTrack VM the adapter light goes off. Here is proof of drivers and USB detection.

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:17ab ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root h
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9c:d5:dc  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe9c:d5dc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:758 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:609 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:381917 (381.9 KB)  TX bytes:159317 (159.3 KB)
          Interrupt:10 Base address:0xd020 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:853 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:853 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:299027 (299.0 KB)  TX bytes:299027 (299.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:60:6e:cd:f8:2c  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               12493  1 
isofs                  39187  1 
vboxvideo              12511  1 
drm                   183453  2 vboxvideo
vboxsf                 38096  0 
dm_crypt               22236  0 
snd_intel8x0           33017  0 
8192cu                503302  0 
snd_ac97_codec        104623  1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus               12602  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm                72878  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
i2c_piix4              12983  0 
snd_rawmidi            24215  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14076  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                50403  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              23911  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         13817  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
ppdev                  12840  0 
snd                    52787  7 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
psmouse                72465  0 
serio_raw              13027  0 
joydev                 17161  0 
lp                     13321  0 
parport_pc             31867  0 
soundcore              12534  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         13709  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
vboxguest             190596  5 vboxsf
mac_hid                13037  0 
parport                34960  3 ppdev,lp,parport_pc
dm_mirror              21585  0 
dm_region_hash         15035  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 17871  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
aufs                  162169  0 
usbhid                 41119  0 
hid                    79842  1 usbhid
pcnet32                40553  0
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect with wireless using `wicd` it will help you.

to open it type this at terminal `wicd &`

or `application --> internet -->wicd`